# Haskell: should I bother compiling regular expressions?

Tags: regex, haskell

My impulse is to say yes, especially if I'm using the same regex in multiple code locations, but [this article](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/) indicates that the library will cache the compilation for me (which I'm not even sure how it would do):

> There’s normally no need to compile regular expression patterns. A pattern will be compiled the first time it’s used, and your Haskell runtime should memoise the compiled representation for you.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: There's a comment down there (by no one else but the author of the package) plainly stating that the quoted statement is not true.

Comment: I wrote that comment, and I still believe that it is not likely to be memoised using the =~ operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reuse a regular expression then it is worthwhile to use the [RegexMaker](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t%3aRegexMaker) type class to define the "compiled" regular expression.  It has the ability to take additional options and the ability to report compilation failure in your choice of Monad.

To use the "compiled" form you can use 'match' or 'matchM' from [RegexLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t%3aRegexLike) which gives you the equivalent to =~ or ==~ operators.

Answer (score 5):

GHC (as of 7.8.4/regex-tdfa-1.2.0) does not memoize regular expressions matched with `(=~)` or `(=~~)`. I see an order of magnitude performance improvement using [`compile` and `execute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-1.2.0/docs/Text-Regex-TDFA-ByteString.html) with a large number of potential matches.

1. [`compile` and `execute`](https://github.com/hakujin/leaves/commit/abdcc4e3ceb84abb3b0bafdf1f85d0a481872307)
2. [`(=~)`](https://github.com/hakujin/leaves/commit/01afae8d83066291c77b0c668600785a97d135ce)